# What does "his arms thrown abroad" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

While I was reading *A Study In Scarlet*, I came across a paraphrase, and I don't understand that description. Here it is: "His hands were clenched and his arms **thrown abroad**, while his lower limbs were interlocked, as though his death struggle had been a grievous one."

I don't understand the phrase that is written in bold text.

Comment: Flung wide, outstretched. Old-fashioned. _Abroad dictionary definitions from Oxford Languages · adverb 1. in or to a foreign country or countries. **2. in different directions; over a wide area.**_

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+arms+abroad%2Cher+arms+abroad&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: Conan Doyle should probably have stuck with [***arms akimbo,***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arms+akimbo%2Carms+thrown+abroad&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) same as everyone else. If you search for *images*, you'll see many people with ***clenched fists*** on their hips.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - This is a dead man with his arms flung out, not with his hands on his hips.

Comment: @KateBunting - 'akimbo' can mean [1] (of arms or legs) stretched out fully, [2] (of arms) bent at the elbows with the hands on the hips [3] (of legs) far apart or bent outwards in an awkward way. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/akimbo). I have to admit I was not aware of [1] and [3].

Answer (score 0):

The verb **thrown** there is not used in the sense of tossing a ball. It means to  cause something to enter a state or condition very suddenly.

> The room was still filled with smoke even though the windows had been thrown open.
>
> Mary Poppins threw open her arms to embrace the children.
>
> A series of natural disasters threw the country into disarray.

See definition #2 [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=throw%20meaning&oq=throw%20meaning&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).